# mapreduce using snappy data order error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, snappy

I meet a problem when I read snappy file on `HDFS` to `mapreduce`.

I have set 
`job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);`
in job.

Then I get the line value in mapper like this

`protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] strs = new String(value.getBytes()).split(String.valueOf(0x09));
    LOGGER.info("strs length is " + strs.length);
}`

If the data is correct, the strs length will be 44. But I found many error length (bigger than 44) in userlogs .

Then I print the value `new String(value.getBytes)`.I found the string printed is not my expected.The line data is not the string I saved to HDFS.

The data's order is error,lead to the wrong value in mapper.

What I can do to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a Snappy Compressed text file but you have mentioned job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class) which means that you are going to read a Text file. You have to first decompressed your file to Text file and then you need to run your MR job on top of that file.